# Is there an upstart event for files systems that get mounted manually?

Tags: mount, upstart

There is the `mounted` event in upstart, but it is emitted only when the *mountall* daemon mounts the devices found in `/etc/fstab` at startup.

Are there any events that get emitted, when I mount a device afterwards manually using the `mount` command or by calling an API?

If not, what would be a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, calling `mount` directly does not cause any Upstart events to be emitted.  However, you can use `initctl emit` to emit the events of your choice.  See the [initctl(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/initctl) manual page.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to add this functionality to upstart?

Comment: I don't know of any explicit plans (though I know that eventually the idea is to integrate mountall into upstart, so something might tie in with that).  I believe you can monitor mounts over a netlink socket, so in that case it ought to be straightforward to write a bridge (like upstart-udev-bridge) that turns mount/unmount events into upstart events.